# memcached memory consumption

Tags: memory, memcached

I set up a memcached on 3 machines with each allocated 4G. I have totally 200M items. Thus, on average, each item has 60 bytes. The hash key is a length 10 string. The hash value is boolean. The memory looks more than enough. However, I still found "evictions" number increases. What's the memcached memory consumption?

Answer (score 3):

Memcached allocates storage based on slabs of fixed sizes, and may therefore waste a lot of memory. If you have very small objects, it will select the smallest slab that is larger than your object, but that may depending on configuration be quite large.

I think you can configure this to some extent, and it may be worthwhile testing with different values for the -n parameter to see if this makes a difference.